# Django how to create button that visible only some type of users

Tags: python, django

I created a system with Django. I have several users and these users can have different `rank`s. I have a page and only '`lead`' users can see the page. In user profile page I want to create a button that visible to only `lead`s.

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    ranks = (
        ..
        ('lead', 'Lead'),
        ('manager', 'Manager'),
        ...
    )
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
def is_lead(user):
    return user.rank == 'lead'

@user_passes_test(is_lead)
@login_required
def lead_page(request):

    return render(request, 'lead.html')
```

**profile.html**

```
<div class="col">
     <a href="/leadpage" class="btn btn-outline-success"> Enter </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check the rank of your user.

```
{% if user.rank == "lead" %}
<div class="col">
     <a href="/leadpage" class="btn btn-outline-success"> Enter </a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Et voilà

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a variable in your `context`, which controls the visibility of your button in the template. So imagine your view does something like:

```
def myview(request):
   # pseudocode!
   context = dict()
   if user is lead:
      context['show-lead-button'] = True
   return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

In your template you have to check this variable:

```
{% if show-lead-button %}
<a href="#">Only lead can see!</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It look like a good solution but I cannot implement it. I am new at Django

Comment: Hi dencelden! Me neither, because I can only give you hints about what you could do - this is no coding service, but I am sure you know that. Please specify what your questions exactly are.